# QGIS : "Add Delimited Text File" from csv ignores precision specified in csvt file

Tags: csv, gdal, qgis

The QGIS documentation for CSVT Files (https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/supported_data.html#csvt-files)
explicitly states:

*You can even specify width and precision of each column, e.g.: "Integer(6)","Real(5.5)","String(22)"
You can find more information at GDAL CSV Driver.*

The GDAL link states that precision support was added in GDAL 2.0 and I have verified that my Windows QGIS install has : Running against GDAL/OGR 2.4.3

However, whatever I try, QGIS seems to ignore all precision and width values and creates fields with the default precision and width. I know that QGIS is using the CSVT file since my test file has integer values that would result in an integer field if the "Real" override in my CSVT was not used.

My test data file ';' delimiter and field headers is:

intval;intwidthval;rval;sval;WKT
9;1;5.5;Hello;LINESTRING(-13615773 6048754,-13615788 6048751,-13615804 6048756,-13615824 6048775)

My test csvt file is:
"Real","Integer(5)","Real","String","String"

Has anyone had any success using the precision and width from a csvt?

Answer (score 0):

according to this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/224143/147040)

> There are two options to load .csv files into QGIS:
>
> 1_ "Add delimited text layer" 2_ "Add vector layer"
>
> If you are loading a .csv with a .csvt you should do it by using “Add vector layer”

I tried adding your data with "Add vector layer" and it gives me `intwidthval` with length 5

Comment: If I add as vector layer, how for I get support for the field headers and specify the delimiter?
The csvt file is definitely being opened for the "Add delimited text layer' since the Real is being applied so it seems strange that it is only partially honored.

Comment: some other findings https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243640/using-csvt-file-to-define-column-field-types-vector-vs-delimited-text-layers

It sounds like a bug to me.